# Angular $http.json promise returning error, though I can see the response

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, angularjs, jsonp

I am somewhat new to working with http promise objects.

I am using Angular JS to return json from an API http://www.asterank.com/api.

I have an angular controller making the call like so:

```
  $http.jsonp('http://www.asterank.com/api/asterank?query={%22e%22:{%22$lt%22:0.1},%22i%22:{%22$lt%22:4},%22a%22:{%22$lt%22:1.5}}&limit=1&callback=JSON_CALLBACK').
success( function(data) {
  console.log('great success');
}).error( function(r,t,et){
  console.log(r);
  console.log(t);
  console.log(et);
});
```

When I check out Chrome's network monitor I see the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 06 Oct 2013 19:06:26 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: gunicorn/18.0
Set-Cookie: session=eyJkaXNjb3Zlcl9maXJzdF90aW1lIjpmYWxzZX0.BTNGMg.eF89vHEeIpLH8sZiJOwCAJEjPhA; HttpOnly; Path=/
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

But I am seeing the error method fire, never the success :(

Is this simply because the server does not support JSONP? How do you access the data of these APIs if they don't support JSONP but they support JSON?

## Found a nice solution:

Just in case anyone comes across this and like me am using EXPRESS, you create create a simple little API on your server using this:

https://npmjs.org/package/request

Here I don't need to spin up a whole proxy server, but you can request the JSON data from your server.

Comment: did you defined the ``JSON_CALLBACK`` function?

Comment: you didn't define JSON_CALLBACK so probably this is the root of error

Comment: Angular handles the JSON_CALLBACK function. -> http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http#jsonp

Comment: What's the response body? If the server does not support JSONP, and you don't have access to change it, you will need to use a proxy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only problem here is that site doesn't even declare JSONP support.

> How do you access the data of these APIs if they don't support JSONP
>   but they support JSON?

Write your proxy layer on backend.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying. I was not 100% sure if the site had to be configured to accept JSONP.

As my backend in this case is NODE/EXPRESS I will look into how to to write a proxy layer.

Thanks for your insight.

Comment: if the external site is not configured for jsonp, how would your back end communicate with it ?

Comment: @eranotzap backend doesn't have same restrictions as browsers have.

Comment: @OZ are you saying that a node process can perform cross domain requests with out the same limitations ?

Comment: @eranotzap yes. (any server-side code, not only nodejs).

Comment: wow that might be a solution for my problem . 
I've got a javascript client running on my browser which just can't do cross domain calls to a rest api exposed by some site. 

in the middle where would you still need to add headers to the request ?
something like this : http://benbuckman.net/articles/cracking-cross-domain-allow-origin-nut/

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
var url = 'http://www.asterank.com/api/asterank?query={%22e%22:{%22$lt%22:0.1},%22i%22:{%22$lt%22:4},%22a%22:{%22$lt%22:1.5}}&limit=1&callback=json_callback';

$http({method: 'GET', url: url })
                .success(function(data,status,headers,config){
                    console.log(data);
                }).error(function(data,status,headers,config){
                    console.log('API CALL ERROR'+status);
                });
        };
```

Comment: What's the difference between this and jsonp ?